# some questions about setMnemonic

Tags: java, swing, mnemonics

I have the code:

```
public class MenuBar extends JFrame {

    public MenuBar() {
        initUI();
    }

    public final void initUI() {

        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();

        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        file.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);

        JMenuItem eMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        JMenuItem oMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Open Another");
        eMenuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);
        oMenuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_O);
        eMenuItem.setToolTipText("Exit application");
        oMenuItem.setToolTipText("Open another Window");
        eMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        oMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                main(null);
            }
        });

        file.add(eMenuItem);
        file.add(oMenuItem);
        menubar.add(file);

        setJMenuBar(menubar);

        setTitle("Simple menu");
        setSize(300, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                MenuBar ex = new MenuBar();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

it works fine but I had a question about setMnemonic. How would you go about making the Mnemonic for eMenuItem just to press E, as opposed to Alt + E? Thanks for any and all help! (Please not I left imports out intentially, for length issues)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setMnemonic%28int%29) of setMnemonic:

> The mnemonic is the key which **when combined with the look and feel's
>   mouseless modifier (usually Alt)** will activate this button if focus is
>   contained somewhere within this button's ancestor window.

Thus using setMnemonic to do this is impossible.

However, you can use the [setAccelerator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenuItem.html#setAccelerator%28javax.swing.KeyStroke%29) method defined for `JMenuItem`s, passing a keystroke like `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('e');`

Alternatively, you could, as Joop Eggen pointed out in the comments to this answer use a [MenuKeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/MenuKeyListener.html) which allows for greater control over the specific *events* that the action is performed on.

Comment: [JMenuItem.addMenuKeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenuItem.html#addMenuKeyListener%28javax.swing.event.MenuKeyListener%29)

Comment: This would only work after the menu has been opened, not usable to open the menu, correct?

Comment: @quixotrykd Indeed. The Menu must have focus.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would work but you can try it out. From this (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_E) we see that the ASCII binding for `VK_E` is 69. This is caps `E`. To get the one for small `e` its 101, which corresponds to `VK_NUMPAD5`. I might be wrong though, its just a guess.

Comment: `KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD5` by definition would cause it to run on events from the 5 key on the num pad...